# How to interpret this probability question?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The probability that you win $i$ dollars $(1 \leq i \leq 5)$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{i}$? What is the probability of winning $i$ dollars for $(1 \leq i \leq 5)$?

I assume that this means:

$P(i=1)=\frac{1}{1}$, $P(i=2)=\frac{1}{2}$, $P(i=3)=\frac{1}{3}$, $P(i=4)=\frac{1}{4}$, $P(i=5)=\frac{1}{5}$...

but the answers should be

$P(i=1)=\frac{60}{137}$, $P(i=2)=\frac{30}{137}$, $P(i=3)=\frac{20}{137}$, $P(i=4)=\frac{15}{137}$, $P(i=5)=\frac{12}{137}$

Comment: You have that $P(i)=k/i.$ You have to get the value of $k.$ Note that you have $P(1)+\cdots +P(5)>1.$

Comment: Any chance you can lead me in the right direction? What exactly does, proportional to $\frac{1}{i}$ mean?

Comment: Sure. $P(1)+\cdots+P(5)=\dfrac{k}{1}+\cdots+\dfrac{k}{5}$ must be equal to one. Get the value of $k.$ (You should get $k=60/137$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B1%2F2%2B1%2F3%2B1%2F4%2B1%2F5).  Then you will know $P(i)=k/i.$

Comment: You're welcome.