# Interpret discrete expected value problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

An $n$-faced fair die, marked with $1,2,3,...,n$ is rolled. What are the expected number of dots of the landed face?

I understand by my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457871/how-to-interpret-this-probability-question?noredirect=1#comment5078428_2457871) that this will be proportional probability. How do I calculate $E[X]$ given these circumstances.

Given formula:

$$E[X]=\sum_{x, p(x)>0}xp(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the value of the dice roll. We are given that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1, 2, \dotsc,n\}$ i.e. $P(X=k)=1/n$ for $k=1,\dotsc, n$.  Observe that $n+1-X$ has the same distribution as $X$. In particular
$$
E(n+1-X)=E(X)
$$
Solve for $E(X)$ using the fact that expectation is linear.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following can help you answer the question:

Since it is fair, we know that $$p(x)=\begin{cases} \frac1n & &, x \in \{ 1, \ldots, n\} \\ 0 & &, \text{Otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Also, the keyword " [arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)" might be helpful for this particular question.

Comment: Would the correct answer me $\frac{n+1}{2}$?

Comment: yes, congratulations.